# What are the advantages and disadvantages of use two layers, one entities and other domain in Entity Framework and C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

Usually when a project is created in C# that can be MVC, ASP.NET, etc, the right thing is to create different layers, are generally layer data, presentation, entities, etc.

1. I have seen in some projects with Entity Framework that it's only a single layer of entities (obj. from database), all operations on the database are performed on these objects
2. But in another projects I have seen two layers, one domain and other entities. The domain layer contains the same objects as the entity layer, then they are other layer called mapper that is responsible for match obj from entities and obj from domain. Here all operations on the database are performed on domain objects

My question is: what are the advantages and disadvantages of these two ways of structuring a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is not complex, but more of CRUD nature, then this answer is not that important. But if you have complexity in your business domain, then this is important.

It has to do with [separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and build applications which are more robust:

1. Changes in one layer should not force changes in another layer.
2. Design decisions/constraints in one layer should not be forced upon other layers.

A typical example is when using Entity Framework or other ORM mappers. If you would design an entity only focusing on the business domain then it would most likely look in one way (using for instance proper [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) etc). But from the Entity Framework perspective, you would do some sacrifices to allow EF to track and handle the entity.

When presenting an entity to a user you might want to adapt it, like printing "n/a" instead of "null" etc. Those changes, to make it more user/view friendly, are also sacrifices.

So instead of getting a single entity which tries to be good at everything we create several representations of the same object type, but for different concerns (presentation, business logic and persistence).

However, if the entities look exactly the same then the design isn't very sound. Business entities typically have a much better object oriented design, while the UI and persistence entities is more of [Data Transfer Objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single silver bullet and it depends on various factors. Here are few factors that I take care when deciding between two:

1. If your application is rich client application like WPF and size of application is going to be moderate to big then consider having separate Domain layer as you may require to implement various interfaces and flags for binding support that makes no sense to EF.
2. If you application is a REST API, then there is no sense of having duplicate classes in Entity and Domain and doing unnecessary conversion all the time. One Entity layer is enough.
3. Even if your app is rich client application but if you are implementing MVVM pattern, then also separate domain layer makes no sense as all UI specific Logic will go into ViewModel classes.

In nutshell, duplicate classes in domain layer only if you are going to have some additional functionality in domain layer so that the cost of duplicacy and conversion can be justified.